# How to send url as slug field into url in Django

Tags: python, django, url, view

I have my `urls.py` as this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('link',views.get_text,name='text'),
    path('link/<link>',views.show,name='show')
]
```

When I enter a `url` like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/link/https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gate-cs-notes-gq/`, it is showing page not found as it is checking the `/` in the slug url. I am storing the url and other fields in database, so I want to retrieve the database objects using the url. How to do such that when I enter a url in the browser, it takes the entire url as `link` field in urls.py , so that I can retrieve the db objects from `views.py` in this way:

```
def show(request,link):
    objs = Links.objects.filter(link=link).values()
    return HttpResponse('link')
```

Comment: The characters in a URL are not valid in a path. You need to pass the URL in a different manner, in the querystring (request.GET) would work: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/link/?link=https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gate-cs-notes-gq/`

Comment: How to define a url and view to do that. I haven't used `?` anytime. So, could you please tell, how to write a respective url for that and how to capture it in views

Comment: What does `views.get_text` do? You could use the same view to handle both cases where a URL is passed or not

Comment: But, how to tell when a URL is passed. I have a problem passing the URL in the url

Comment: Everything that follows the "?" will be passed without problems and will be in request.GET, it does not need to be declared

Comment: When I tried the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/link/?link=https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gate-cs-notes-gq/` , it is showing Page Not Found Error

Comment: but remove <link> in: path('link/<link>',views.show,name='show'), like this :path('link$',views.show,name='show')

Comment: It's working as of now. Now how to redirect from another view?

Comment: django redirect: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the URL in the querystring of the requesting URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/link/?link=https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gate-cs-notes-gq/`

The data from the querystring is available in the `request.GET` dictionary in your view

```
def link_view(request):
    if 'link' in request.GET:
        objs = Links.objects.filter(link=request.GET['link']).values()
        return HttpResponse(...)
    else:
        # Handle no link provided (views.get_text)
```

Your url patterns then only need to define one path that handles both cases where a URL is provided or not

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('link/', views.link_view, name='link_view'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

To redirect, you can use `HttpResponseRedirect`. It will redirect the url without specifying the view. It you write `HttpResponseRedirect('/link')`, it will redirect you to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/link`. Since you mentioned, redirect from another view, you do in this way:

```
def link_view(request):
    if 'link' in request.GET:
        objs = Links.objects.filter(link=request.GET['link']).values()
        return HttpResponse(...)
    else:
        # do something when no link provided (views.get_text)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/link?'+str(link))#str(link) is the url you want to get
```